# How can I remove all breakpoints from NetBeans 6.8?

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I remove all breakpoints from NetBeans 6.8?

Comment: I noticed that my java application was running really slow in NetBeans 8.0 debugger. I saw I had lots & lots of DISABLED breakpoints but removing all the unneeded ones as described here, made a big improvement in startup time.

Answer (score 118):

Select menu Window / Debugging / Breakpoints (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>), then right-click in the Breakpoints window and select Delete All.

Comment: Still applies to Netbeans 7.2

Comment: And 7.4 (some 4 years later)

Comment: On NetBeans7.4 removed from list, but it still not disappeared from line numbers.. Had to restart NetBeans, then OK.

Comment: On 8.2, you might also want to click the gear icon on the breakpoints pane, deselect "From Opened Projects Only" and delete those too. I had breakpoints lying around from long-deleted projects.

Answer (score 23):

The top answer is how to permanently remove the breakpoints. You can also *temporarily* remove all breakpoints by using Disable All instead of Delete All.

Select menu Window / Debugging / Breakpoints (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>), then right-click in the Breakpoints window and select Disable All.

Works in NetBeans 7.4 (and NetBeans 8)

Comment: @james.garriss top answer is how to delete. I didn't want to delete, didn't realize I could disable. Posted to help rookies like me in the future. No harm intended. :)

Comment: Disable vs Delete.  I missed that.  My bad.

Answer (score 4):

In 6.0 it was in the  Window | Debugging menu.

You can right click then choose "Delete All".

Answer (score 3):

just to confirm that this answer works in Netbeans 8.1 (answer by YCF_L)
Select menu Window / Debugging / Breakpoints (or press Alt + Shift + 5), then right-click in the Breakpoints window and select Disable All.

Works in NetBeans 7.4 (and NetBeans 8)

Answer (score 2):

You have two options - disable and delete the breakpoints. Disable keeps the position of the breakpoint but debugger doesn't stop there delete removes the breakpoint completely. To delete breakpoints go to Window-> Debugger and select "Delete All".

Answer (score 0):

adding at the other responses, after go to the next rout:
Windows/Debugging/Breakpoints (or Alt + Shift + 5), then right-click at the breakpoints window you can Disable or Delete one or more breakpoints. Disable all or Delete all, and select the option Go to the source and see where ie the breakpoint.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Break points can also be deleted whilst debugging by selecting them in the breakpoints tab (next to the variables and call stack tabs) and then deleting with the delete button or mouse right click menu.