# Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint wicket on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, breakpoints

I'm using Netbeans on Ubuntu. I opened a Wicket application. My project had three packages. But I deleted one. It has EventCollection. Now My Project has two packages. Now I want to run it but it is not run. It gives error.

I did debug. It gives this error:

```
Attaching to localhost:11555
Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint EventCollection.java : 95, reason: The breakpoint is set outside of any class.
Invalid LineBreakpoint EventCollection.java : 95
User program running
```

Than name of existed package change with Events and  name of CategoryCollection.java change with EventCollection.java

Comment: Have you tried removing the breakpoint in the IDE?

Comment: NO. how to removing the breakpoint in the IDE

Comment: I don't use netbeans, but take a look at this question [remove breakepoint in netbeans 6.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941415/remove-breakepoint-in-netbeans-6-8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove that breakpoint from the IDE. I don't use NetBeans but this question seems to suggest that you can find this option under the Window / Debugging / Breakpoints menu.  [remove breakepoint in netbeans 6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941415/remove-breakepoint-in-netbeans-6-8/2942096#2942096).

Also, these links might be useful to you: 
**[NetBeans Docs & Support](http://netbeans.org/kb/index.html)**
**[Getting Started With the NetBeans IDE Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/tools/netbeans_part1/)**

Comment: If it's a persistent problem, it could be that the breakpoint comes after unreachable code which the compiler optimizes out. (I had `if (1==1) return;` earlier in a method to prevent it from happening, forgot to remove it, and spent a while trying to determine why a breakpoint later in that method was an "invalid line".)

Answer (score 2):

Just to delete all contente from folder: C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.1